# Oksendal. Stohastic differential equations. Problem 4.7

Tags: martingales, measurable-functions

I am stacked at problem 4.7 (b) in the book Oksendal. Stohastic Differential equations.

The conditions of the problem are the next:

Let $X_{t}$ be an Ito integral.

$dX_{t}=v\left(t,\omega\right)dB_{t}\left(\omega\right)$ where $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $v\in\mathcal{V}\left(0,T\right)$, $B_{t}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $0\leq t\leq T$

Prove that if $v$ is bounded then $M_{t}=X_{t}^{2}-\int\left|v_{s}\right|^{2}ds$ is a martingale, where $\left\langle X,X\right\rangle _{t}:=\int\left|v_{s}\right|^{2}ds$ quadratic variation of the martingale process $X_{t}$ .

Part of my solution is the next:

1. Let's consider the process $M_{t}=X_{t}^{2}-\int_{0}^{t}\left|v_{s}\right|^{2}ds$.
2. According to Corollary 3.2.6 we have to show that $M_{t}$ can be represented in the form of $M_{t}\left(\omega\right)=\int_{0}^{t}f\left(s,\omega\right)dB_{s}$, because this process is a martingale. $(f\left(t,\omega\right)\in\mathcal{V}\left(0,T\right))$
3. According to Ito formula we have $dM_{t}=-\left|v_{t}\right|^{2}dt+2X_{t}dX_{t}+\left(dX_{t}\right)^{2}$
4. Using the definition of $dX_{t}$ and substituting it at (3) we have that $dM_{t}=-\left|v_{t}\right|^{2}dt+2X_{t}v\left(t,\omega\right)dB_{t}\left(\omega\right)+\left(v\left(t,\omega\right)dB_{t}\left(\omega\right)\right)^{2}$
5. Simplifying terms in (4) the equation can be simplifyed to $dM_{t}=2X_{t}v\left(t,\omega\right)dB_{t}\left(\omega\right)\implies M_{t}=M_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}2X_{s}v\left(s,\omega\right)dB_{s}$
6. Let's assume that $M_{0}=0$ and we next have to prove that $2X_{t}v\left(t,\omega\right)\in\mathcal{V}\left(0,T\right)$

I have to prove the statement in point (6) to finish the proof.
What do I need to do next, to get the needed result?

For convenience, I add the definition of $\mathcal{V}\left(0,T\right)$ space in the picture:

> [image: For convenience, I add the definition of <span class=]$\mathcal{V}\left(0,T\right)$ space in the picture" />

Comment: Why not try to prove $M_t$ is a martingale by definition: $E[M_t |F_s] = M_s$? It would be easier

Comment: I think you are right. It is more optimal trajectory of proof, but I am interested in completing the proof the above way:)

Comment: I didnot check your steps. If you want to prove (6). $E[\int^T_0 X_s^2 v_s^2 ds] \leq M E[\int^T_0 X_s^2 ds] < \infty $

Comment: What about "1)" in the definition? How can I prove that $2X_{t}v\left(t,\omega\right)$ is $\mathbb{B}\times\mathcal{F}$ measurable? Does any martingale is $\mathbb{B}\times\mathcal{F}$ measurable? I think I can use the statement that product of two measurable ($v\left(t,\omega\right)$ and $X_{t}$ and $f(t, \omega)$=2) functions is measurable function which completes the proof of statement of "1)" and implies the "2)" statement

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. 
1) By definition any stohastic process is $\mathbb{B}\times\mathcal{F}$. That implies that $X_{t}$ $\mathbb{B}\times\mathcal{F}$. measurable
2) Any constant function is measurable
3) Product of tho measurable function is measurable
4) Because $v\left(t,\omega\right)\in\mathcal{V}\left(0,T\right)$ using (2) and (3) $2X_{t}v\left(t,\omega\right)$ is $\mathbb{B}\times\mathcal{F}$ measurable and the point "1)" is finished

Right?

Comment: Yes, I advise you to reread a few chapters on measure theory, it would help you solidify your background a bit before advancing towards SDE. Books by Schilling and Le Gall should work out for you. And you should go the easiest path first (like proving martingale just by using definition)...